# Negotiate traffic speed for mobile applications - algorithm?

Tags: performance, algorithm, statistics, traffic

we have 2 devices - iPad A & iPad B. Both use the same application that is designed to send audio/video data.

Sometimes devices are located far away from each other and traffic goes through internet instead of local network.

In that case, we can't guarantee the same network speed on both ends. One device may send 512Kb/s another one 5 times less.

Question is -

Is it possible to measure traffic between both devices in real time and scale up/down when needed. For example if I know that device A has only 256kb/s incoming connection at this given moment, then device B should scale down from 1mb/s to 256kb/s automatically

Right now the solution we have implemented is to detect the traffic/speed degradation by recognizing lost packets. But it's not perfect.

Maybe you have read something or have an idea in mind?

thanks in Advance,
Dmitry

Comment: your proposed solution makes sense over an amount of time. You can downgrade to 256kb/s for a minute then next minute, you will have to downgrade to say 200kb/s.

Answer (score 2):

If you use [TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) as your network layer - the protocol already does it for you in its [flow control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Flow_control). The protocol also ensures packets will reach their destination<sup>1</sup>

If you don't use TCP for some reason, you can follow the ideas the protocol uses - with its sliding window (The wikipedia article describes the concepts of this idea).

However, since you probably want reliable connection - and you also want to ensure traffic speed as a result - I'd suggest using the Off the shelf solution and chose TCP as your network protocol.

---

(1) Up to a certain limit, after a number of failing trials the package will be thrown out - but that seldom occures AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks Amit, we're using UDP to send traffic.

Comment: @DmitrySemenov: Then just try to replicate the TCP protocol that does it, and if possible - switch to TCP (I am aware that might be impossible, but it at least worth thinking about it)